# How to create popup in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, popup

I'm using material ui, there is an example how to create popup http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog.

My question is what would be best practices here? Should I add this component in app render method so it will be created on app start and show/hide it as I need or it would be better to create it on the fly when i need it?

Since it's a popup it kinda make more sense to me to create it when/if I need it. My concern is how React collect this used components, is it efficient regarding memory, tracking reference to old objects ...

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it would be better to put it under the main app.
After that you can keep two actions in the redux part (showDialog(), hideDialog() ) that changes a Boolean value (open) that will be used to show and close the dialog.
Let the main app listen to the store for this value and whenever necessary you just need to call showDialog() action which will change the store value of 'open' and then render the main app with the dialog..